Image not displaying inside of div on HTML site
I am new to HTML and CSS, and I am programming an online portfolio for myself. When attempting to add a background image with the usage of a div and external CSS, I am unable to get the image to load after over an hour of straight troubleshooting.
Image and CSS file are sourced correctly
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> A website about myself </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css\app.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="banner">
</div>

</body>

<script src="js\app.js"></script>

</html>

CSS:
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.banner{
width: 100%;
height: 100%vh;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-image: url(/assets/bg/WebsiteBackground.png);
}

I attempted to change the location of the image, file type, location of the "Background Image" line in the CSS file, and Div name. The html file still results in a blank screen however.

height: 100%vh; should be height: 100vh;

additionally, the external CSS and JS files may not load due to using backslashes instead of forward slashes

Is your code on the server? If not, url(/assets/bg/WebsiteBackground.png) won't work. Getting that path right (the path from the CSS file to the image) is critical. Where is the image in relation to the CSS file?

Are you using your browsers devtools inspect facility to check why the image isn’t loading? E.g. the address you show for the css file looks incorrect.

The back slash is going the wrong direction in the script tag. Also, not a fix but the <link> tag does not use and does not need a closing slash.

@TimR How did I not notice this lol, it was one of the things I had done earlier as I was attempting to fix it. This, in combination with Brett's fix, solved it. Many thanks!

If you are working with files on your computer, the URL in the background-image style rule needs to be the path to the image relative to the CSS file. So if your directory structure is like this ...
my-web-project    
  index.html
  styles
    style.css
  assets
    bg
      WebsiteBackground.png

... then the path from the CSS file to the image is first to go back up one directory level, then down into assets/bg. So the correct CSS declaration would be:
background-image: url(../assets/bg/WebsiteBackground.png);

But if your directory structure is like this ...
my-web-project    
  index.html
  style.css
  assets
    bg
      WebsiteBackground.png

... then the correct CSS declaration would be:
background-image: url(assets/bg/WebsiteBackground.png);


Hello Brent! Thank you for the follow-up. However, when applying this fix, "../assets/bg/WebsiteBackground.png" the image still did not load. The pathing is correct on the image as I am able to load the image in VSC.

The setup for the folder goes as following
-.vs
-assets
-bg
-WebsiteBackground.png
-css
-app.css
-js
-app.js
index.html

Apologies, I had the VH setup incorrectly as it was one of the fixes I attempted. When corrected, This worked. Many thanks!
